# Read and print the CSS values of a class with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing

I am trying to create a function, which:

- Grabs an element with a specific data element, i.e. "data-findDeclaration = element"
- From this element, the class is read
- It reads out all the css values appointed to this class
- Displays inside another specific data element (i.e. data-writeDeclaration="element") all the classes' rules/values.

Here's where I am so far:

**HTML**:

```
    <span class="slap0" data-finddeclaration="element">The great white fox</span>
    <div class="description" data-writedeclaration="element">

    </div>

    <span class="slap1" data-finddeclaration="element">The great white fox</span>
    <div class="description" data-writedeclaration="element">

    </div>

    <span class="slap2" data-finddeclaration="element">The great white fox</span>
    <div class="description" data-writedeclaration="element">

    </div>

    <span class="slap3" data-finddeclaration="element">The great white fox</span>
    <div class="description" data-writedeclaration="element">

    </div>
```

**JS**:

```
function readOutCssRules() {
var dataElement = document.querySelectorAll('[data-finddeclaration="element"]');
var classRules = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
var writeDataElement = document.querySelectorAll('[data-writedeclaration="element"]');

for (var i = 0; i < dataElement.length; i++) {
    dataElement[i].className;
    if (classRules[i].selectorText == "." + dataElement[i].className) {
        console.log(classRules[i].cssText);

        writeDataElement[i].innerHTML = classRules[i].cssText;
    }
}


}
readOutCssRules();
```

But the function is not working as expected. 
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting in your browser console?

Comment: I do get the contents of the class, but if I add more elements to the html structure, it won't display them.
Plus, I need to see the rules and not the class names, properly displayed inside the corresponding div.

I am not allowed to use jQuery, otherwise this wouldn't be much of a problem :)

Comment: why are you checking if CSS == Class?

Comment: Is that specifically what you want to accomplish? You could just append the class on.

Comment: @HudsonPH If I don't check it, it unloads the whole stylesheet... :/

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard Yes, but every proposal will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Sidius Yeah, if the end goal is to pass the CSS values to another element I see no reason why you wouldn't want to do that. You'd just be redundantly inventing something that already exists and is much simpler.

Comment: @Sidius can you check my answer?

Comment: @HudsonPH I did. Left a comment also. It's a better approach, but same issue with me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working.

You just have to remove one line in the for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataElement.length; i++) {
    //dataElement[i].className;   --> remove this
    if (classRules[i].selectorText == "." + dataElement[i].className) {
        console.log(classRules[i].cssText);

        writeDataElement[i].innerHTML = classRules[i].cssText;
    }
}
```

After that changes it will work, as you can see in [this](http://jsbin.com/jugavusogo/edit?html,css,js,output) fiddle.

Comment: Sadly not...
The CSS is displayed only if the classes are present and if I add more elements, the newer rules are not displayed at all.

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: The function is called, and searches through the HTML for the tags 
data-finddeclaration="element".
Every time it meets one, it reads out the class that belongs to this element. Through the class, it grabs its rules/values.
Then by using data-writedeclaration="element", it posts those rules, without showing the class, just the rules in the brackets.

Comment: So you just have to add a simple string replace:   writeDataElement[i].innerHTML = classRules[i].cssText.replace("." + dataElement[i].className, ""); . Check the fiddle again.

Comment: Implemented it, but the problems that occur, are the following:
If inserted in a real CSS stylesheet, with reset rules and all the other stuff, the loop length is not enough to find the classes. 
Another problem which I already encountered, is that if a class is duplicated, it wont be displayed. 

Thanks for the effort, I am trying to work with what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

https://jsfiddle.net/g6tu77mg/1/

```
var element = classRules[i].cssText
var css= element.substring(element.lastIndexOf("{")+1,element.lastIndexOf("}"));
writeDataElement[i].innerHTML = css;
```

Output:

```
The great white fox
color: blue;
The great white fox
color: red;
The great white fox
color: yellow;
```

Comment: Implemented it, but the problems that occur, are the following:
If inserted in a real CSS stylesheet, with reset rules and all the other stuff, the loop length is not enough to find the classes. 
Another problem which I already encountered, is that if a class is duplicated, it wont be displayed. 

Thanks for the effort, I am trying to work with what you posted.

Comment: In this case you need make a validation for every type :/

Comment: I was afraid of that myself... I hoped there was something I was missing. But thank you so much for your input.